# Lissajous table Pattern in Blender Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, mathematics

Is it possible to create all these [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) patterns in Blender Geometry Nodes and animate them at the same time?

If yes, how? Will really appreciate any kind of help.

[image: Lissajous table Pattern]

[image: Lissajous table Pattern]

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-positions-of-all-curves-in-a-lissajous-curve-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but one way would be the following:

[image]

Here I use a grid as a basis, whose points I mark in advance column-wise and row-wise and multiply with a per frame incrementing value. This way I get the base values for the animation.

[image]

<sub>(The indices of the points corresponding to the rows)</sub>

[image]

<sub>(The indices of the points corresponding to the columns)</sub>

Then I instantiate circles on this grid and recalculate the positions of the circle points using the previously captured values:

[image]

In the animation it then looks like this:

[image]

*Please excuse the brevity of this post, I know this isn't explained very well, but I don't have the time right now and just wanted to give you a quick example...*

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

Comment: This is so cool! To those wondering how those Lissajous Curves work, apparently you draw a circle by moving a cursor to $x = \cos(aθ)$ and $y = \sin(bθ)$, where $a = b = 1$ to draw a circle, but as you modify $a$ and $b$, either horizontal or vertical movement accelerates (in time, the circle rather than stretching in either dimension gets sine and cosine desynchronized) which produces those wonderful patterns.

Answer (score 4):

I might be breaking the site rules, but inspired by quellenform's answer, I created this little toy which visualizes the logic: so it's a [full gantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantry_crane), but instead of a crane block hanging from the beam, it just has a huge pen attached to it. The *beam* is on the *berth*, so it moves relatively to it (notice how in the setup it's moved on $y$ axis, then joined with the *berth*, and then together with the *berth* it's moved on the $x$ axis).

[image]

Now, each of the two, the *berth* and the *beam*, move in a sinusoidal pattern:

[image]

That is, when the animation starts, the *beam* (red on the graph) starts at the middle of the *berth*, goes backwards ($+y$) at full speed but slows down, and slows more and more strongly as it approaches its extreme (pen's $y = 1$), at which it fully stops and immediately reverses, accelerating more and more - until it reaches the middle of the *berth* it slides on, then the motion repeats in a mirrored fashion; the vertical axis above is $y$ coordinate of the pen attached to the *beam* (the center of the *beam*), and the horizontal axis is <strike>the time that has passed</strike> the energy supplied by the PSU - Power Supply Unit.

The *berth* moves in the same way, except it moves on the $x$ axis (the vertical axis on the graph is $x$) and it starts at its rightmost extreme - so the graph is shifted (blue).

Obviously the red line shown on the graph is *sine*, and the shifted blue pattern is *cosine*. Here's the mentioned movements (marked orange) and their combination (marked yellow):

[image]

The reason why I decided to call the horizontal axis of the graph the "energy supplied" rather than just time passed, is that there is only one global time, but I can have independent Power Supply Units - one for the *berth* and one for the *beam*; that's how the animation above was done, the left object had *beam PSU* set to $0$, and the right had *berth PSU* set to $0$. But what if both elements are supplied with power, but at different intensities?

[image]

It doesn't look as neat as in quellenform's answer or in the question, because I modified it while it was running, now I'll do so prior to playing the animation:

[image]

Of course being able to modify the power supply during the animation opens new possibilities, e.g. *berth PSU* = `tau / 100` and *beam PSU* = `#tau/100 * (fmod(frame, 100) < 25)`:

[image]

[image]