# Make #frame active only in some frames

Tags: drivers

I made a gear chain and I used #frame/7 to make it rotate continously, and I wanted to know if there is a way to make it start and stop after specific frames and also if there is a way to ease in and out the start and end of the driver.

Comment: The problem you don't realize is that if you disable a driver on a given frame, the evaluated value won't stay on the last value evaluated by the driver. See the comments (For an easy answer) and Stef's answers (For a mathematical approach) here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/306627/60486

Answer (score 2):

you can use if-statements in drivers. So to make it start and stop you can e.g. do this:

```
frame/20 if frame > 10 and frame < 50 else 50/20
```

If the if statement is true, it executes the command before the if, here: "frame/20".
The else statement is 50/20, because if the gear stops rotating, it is frame 50 and then it should "stay" in the rotation position.

Note: if you really wanna start and stop your gear multiple times, i would recommend using keyframes.

for easing i am using this formula:

```
-(Math.cos(Math.PI * x) - 1) / 2
```

so if you now use this and use it for these values:

frame start: 10
frame end: 50

you can use this as a driver:

```
50/20 if frame > 50 else 50/20*(cos(pi*((frame-10)/40))-1)/(-2) if frame > 10 else 0
```

and you will get:

[image]